# Manually creating XSLT

Tags: xslt, xml-parsing

I am very new to XSL concepts and I am trying to create a XSLT for the below XML,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<row>
  <c1>1234</c1>
  <c2>A</c2>
  <c2 m="1" s="2">321</c2>
  <c2 m="1" s="3">654</c2>
  <c2 m="1" s="4">098</c2>
  <c2 m="2">B</c2>
  <c2 m="3">C</c2>
  <c2 m="3" s="2">123</c2>
  <c2 m="4">5</c2>
  <c3 />
</row>
```

If transform using the XSL then I should get the output to be as follows,

1234 A\321\654\098]B]C\123]5

I have tried creating my own as below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="row">
    <array />
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="c1">
    <data>
      <xsl:attribute name="attribute">1</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="value">
        <xsl:number level="single" />
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="subvalue">1</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </data>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="c2">
    <data>
      <xsl:attribute name="attribute">1</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="value">
        <xsl:number level="single" />
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="subvalue">1</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </data>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but I get the output as follows,

```
1234 A 321 654 098 B C 123 5
```

Kindly help me out in creating the XSL

Comment: The supplied xslt transforms from xml to xml, not xml to text.  Is there a subsequent transformer being used?  Are you looking for `xsl:text`?

Comment: @Arunkumar Can you please explain the logic you've used to get `]` and \ in the output?

Comment: @Mitch I am not using any other transformers. As I told you am very new to XSL so if by using xsl:text the output I have requested can be achived then am very glad.

Comment: @LingamurthyCS I don't use any logic, actually I don't know. I want the output as
1234
A\321\654\098]B]C\123]5

Comment: @Arunkumar How can you expect someone to fix your code without knowing the logic you want to achieve output on?

Comment: May be the output I have requested is creating the confusion here. If I would have requested the output has below it might helped out,

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<array>
<data attribute="1" value="1" subvalue="1">AC</data>
<data attribute="2" value="1" subvalue="1">A</data>
<data attribute="2" value="1" subvalue="2">321</data>
<data attribute="2" value="1" subvalue="3">654</data>
<data attribute="2" value="1" subvalue="4">098</data>
<data attribute="2" value="2" subvalue="1">B</data>
<data attribute="2" value="3" subvalue="1">C</data>
<data attribute="2" value="3" subvalue="2">123</data>
<data attribute="2" value="4" subvalue="1">5</data>
</array>

Comment: @Arunkumar Please don't post code in comments. Add this to your question and include a short explanation of the logic you want to apply here. I see no logical way by which "1234" turns into "AC". And where do the values required for `@attribute`, `@value` and `@subvalue` come from?

Answer (score 0):

This is all very confusing. Your XSLT generates `<array>` and `<data>` elements, with various attributes, but there are no such elements or attributes in your desired output. In fact your sample code seems to bear absolutely no relationship to your desired output.

It's always hard to reverse-engineer requirements from a single example, but my attempt to do so would be this:

- Output the string values of the children of the `row` element
- If `@m1` is greater than the previous `@m1`, precede the string value with "]"
- If `@m1` is equal to the previous `@m1`, precede it with "\"
- If there is no `@m1`, precede it with a single space.

If my guesses are anywhere close to the mark, then the solution would look something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="row">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="row/*[@m1 > preceding-sibling::*[1]/@m1]">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(']', .)"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="row/*[@m1 = preceding-sibling::*[1]/@m1]">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat('\', .)"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="row/*[not(@m1)]">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(' ', .)"/>
</xsl:template>
```